# How can I make a God/Sun ray effect in blender when also using an HDRI?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, volumetrics

I have used the so-called "god ray" effect in many of my projects with manual lighting. But this time I have added an HDRI.So even if I add a volume scatter node or principled volume node to the world output volume to make the god ray it totally ignores the HDRI. Or in other words, the HDRI is not visible at all. So, I am just asking for the god ray effect node setup with the HDRI. Thank you. BTW I am using cycles

[image]

my current node setup

Comment: you need both- "real" lights and an HDRI. There's add-ons that will line a sun lamp up with the sun in your HDRI so the shadows stay the same, look for "HDRI Sun Align" on Google/BlenderMarket

Comment: thanks but is there any other way without the use of paid addons?

Comment: They're not all paid https://github.com/akej74/hdri-sun-aligner

Comment: ok thanks joseph

Comment: Hi :). I don't think World materials support Volumetrics and HDRI at the same time. Try a large mesh cube as the volumetrics domain, that should work better ;)

Comment: ok thanks jachym I`ll keep that in mind